# Simple terminal command: Permanently turn off/on monitor display. (no screensaver, no lockscreen)

Tags: linux, display

The following command should do this at execution:

> - Screen turns off display permanently, nothing like(screensaver, lockscreen). Just a simple turn off display command, everything else keeps working as it was.
> - Screen should NOT back on when touch any keyboard keys/mouse moment/mouse clicks. Only tru a similar command.

Comment: You can try some solutions from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line)

Comment: do you have X running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have X11, try

xset dpms 0 0 1
xset +dpms

This will set the off period to 1 second... but it will turn on if you move the mouse/keyboard... you will need to turn off also the mouse and keyboard (dont know exactly how, probably the X11 have some new way to do this)... but then, how would you turn it on again? via ssh?

you can also do a chvt to switch to a console

```
chvt 1
```

will change the screen to the console 1

when in the he console, you will need to turn it off, please check this response:

[Turn off monitor (energy saving) while in text console mode (in Linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/206622/turn-off-monitor-energy-saving-while-in-text-console-mode-in-linux)